# Display a div only for few seconds in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I want to display a notification on angular app only for few seconds, the event is triggered after clicking a button.

Comment: do you mean something like toast message? https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--eLZxo9PL--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_66%2Cw_880/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jlkiri/use-animate-presence/main/assets/smooth-popup.gif

Comment: yes exactly, is the code available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

html

```
<button (click)="showDiv()">Click</button>
<div *ngIf="!hideDivFlg">My Div</div>
```

.ts

```
showDiv() {
    this.hideDivFlg = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hideDivFlg = true;
    }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, do you mind a quick modification please ? adding (click) event with a button, i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: added the html that goes with it

Comment: it gets a little more complicated if you want the div to fade in and out, but that can be done with css and a little javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a npm package for toast messages:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

`npm install ngx-toastr --save`
*please check the angular version for compatibility*

| ngx-toastr | Angular |
| --- | --- |
| 11.3.3 | 8.x |
| 12.1.0 | 9.x |
| 13.2.1 | 10.x 11.x |
| 14.3.0 | 12.x 13.x |
| 15.2.2 | 14.x. |
| current | >= 15.x |

`npm install @angular/animations --save`

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
...
imports: [
...
ToastrModule.forRoot(),
...]
```

**styles.css**

```
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr';
```

**angular.json**

```
 "styles": [
             ...
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
```

create a new service

**common.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IndividualConfig, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

export interface toastPayload {
  message: string;
  title: string;
  ic: IndividualConfig;
  type: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  showToast(toast: toastPayload) {
    this.toastr.show(
      toast.message,
      toast.title,
      toast.ic,
      'toast-' + toast.type
    );
  }
}
```

Finally use it in your component:

**items-component.ts**

```
import { CommonService, toastPayload } from 'src/app/services/common.service';

export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  toast!: toastPayload;
constructor(private cs: CommonService,)

}

displayToast(){
    this.toast = {
      message: 'A cool Message',
      title: 'A cool Title',
      type: "success",
      ic: {
        timeOut: 2500,
        closeButton: true,
      } as IndividualConfig,
    };
   this.cs.showToast(this.toast);
}
```

[image: Example]